# Copy each files contents into new filenames (using grep/sed/awk if needed)

Tags: unix, awk, grep

How to, using grep, sed, cat or awk (not xmlstarlet), copy each files contents and copy them into new filenames ?

It must be taken into consideration that the only files to be considered will be named in this way:

> Toto.O.1.applist.xml
>
> Toto.O.2.applist.xml
>
> Toto.O.3.applist.xml
>
> Toto.O.4.applist.xml
>
> ......

I know that to take all theses files in consideration, i must use this syntax:

```
Toto.O.*.applist.xml
```

Also take into consideration that any user (s) can create a file following the naming explained above, that they can create as much as they want and that the contents of these files can contain letters, numbers, numbers, spaces as well as points.

Let's take an example of an example of what could be created:

> Toto.O.1.applist.xml
>   Content: abc.def3.g H2k
>
> Toto.O.2.applist.xml
>   Content: Rara df.epc.siunX.zefin
>
> Toto.O.3.applist.xml
>   Content: LULU g32.zfreuf.CdtTGCTG
>
> Toto.O.4.applist.xml
>   Content: 61FGRf XC.efde.444
>
> Etc....

Expected result:

`/DIRECTORY_OF_RESULT/blablabla.abc.def3.g H2k.xml`

`/DIRECTORY_OF_RESULT/Rara df.epc.siunX.zefin.xml`

`/DIRECTORY_OF_RESULT/LULU g32.zfreuf.CdtTGCTG.xml`

`/DIRECTORY_OF_RESULT/61FGRf XC.efde.444.xml`

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: explain your expected result in details

Comment: Please use code tags for your sample(s) and explain the 3 things. 1- what is your question with sample input in code tags. 2- What is your expected results sample in code tags. 3- what you have tried so far?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest As i have write: i want to know how to copy each contents of files names "ExSDCard.O.*.applist.xml" (where * could be 1,2,3,4,5,6,etc...) and past each of them in new filenames.
Of course I have tried several approaches taking answers from this same forum (other similarly similar topics), with sed, cat, grep and awk but I do not handle these tools every day and some uses are enough special I will say. Every time and whatever the tool I can not find the right mix if I can say. That's why I come to ask you answer.

Comment: What will be the contents of the file `/DIRECTORY_OF_RESULT/blablabla.abc.def3.g H2k.xml`?  We only know the filename is derived from one of the source files as a line.  Also, why are the extension is `xml` while not looking like xml files?

Comment: @karakfa About the contents of the new XML files that will be created, i have already my shell script: sed command to copy content from a template file by replacing each time the content between delimiters " in each new created files that will have been created in the current step undergoing work.
"Also, why are the extension is xml while not looking like xml files?" that is to say?

Answer (score 1):

didn't fully understand what you're trying to do and why all the unnecessary complexity is there, but here is something perhaps will make the question more concrete.

Read the lines from files of certain file name pattern and create files with the names from those lines.

For example:
template file name "list?"

```
$ head path3/list?
==> path3/list1 <==
1
2
3

==> path3/list2 <==
10
11
12


$ cat path3/list? | while read -r f; do touch path3/"$f".xml; done

$ ls path3
1.xml  10.xml  11.xml  12.xml  2.xml  3.xml  list1  list2
```

The questions open:  What are the contents of these files?  Why the initial template files have xml extension even though the contents are assumed to be filenames?

Answer (score 0):

Just to feedback to my main question, i have find with wich command i have done that:

```
VARNAMES=$(awk '{ print }' TXT_FILES_*_.txt)
    cd 
        printf '%s\n' "$NAMES" | while IFS= read -r line
        do
        sed "s/com.package.name/$line/" < FOLDER/TEXTFILEEXEMPLE.xml >  FOLDER/FINAL_FILE-$line.xml
```

Thank you @karakfa and others for trying help me.